# instanceof возвращает false

Tags: javascript

В консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тот же параграф внутри функции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пояснения:   этот параграф находится  внутри `iframe`, помещается он туда путем `innerHTML` из `textarea`. Тот же код но при обычной разметке отрабатывает нормально, т.е. `instanceof` возвращает true, хотя этот же параграф вставленный из текстового поля на первом скрине.... мистика...

Исходя из второго скриншота видно, что в массиве лежит один элемент, его конструктор `HTMLParagraphElement`, значит он наследовался от `HTMLElement`, тот в свою очередь от `Element` и `Node`. Но проверка на `instanceof` возвращает `false`, почему так происходит?

Полностью воспроизвести код здесь не удается, поэтому привожу отдельно листинг js файла.

```
(function () {

    /**
     * Конструктор объекта консоли ифрэйма
     * 
     * @param {any} doc 
     * @returns объект консоли
     */
    function FrameConsole(doc) {
        var console = Object.assign({}, window.console);
        var consoleStyle = doc.createElement('style');
        consoleStyle.textContent = ''; // вставить стили для консоли
        doc.head.appendChild(consoleStyle);

        /**
         * @param {any} e  new Date
         * @returns возвращает дату в виде строки "часы:минуты:секунды.миллисекунды"
         */
        function getDate(date) {
            date = new Date(date.valueOf() - 6e4 * date.getTimezoneOffset());
            var dateString = date.toISOString().replace("Z", "");
            return dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf("T") + 1);
        }

        /**
         * Преобразует входящие данные к строке
         * 
         * @param {any} data - входящие данные
         * @returns итоговый результат
         */
        // добавить вывод тегов
        function stringConvert(data) {
            var b = data[0].constructor;
            var c = data[0] instanceof HTMLElement; //!!!! здесь хром возвращает false, не пробовал оперу и ИЕ, в мозиле работает.
            data.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
                if(item instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    alert(true );
                } else {
                     alert(false);
                }

                switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(item)) {
                    case "[object Array]":
                    case "[object Object]":
                        arr[i] = JSON.stringify(item);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
        /**
         * генерирует строки в консоле
         * 
         * @param {any} data arguments метода console
         */
        function genericRow(data) {
            var eventContainer = doc.body.querySelector('.console');
            var eventDate = doc.createElement('span');
            var eventData = doc.createElement('p');
            var eventCode = doc.createElement('code');
            eventDate.className = 'console_date';
            eventData.className  = 'console_text';
            eventCode.className  = 'console_code';
            eventCode.textContent = stringConvert(data);
            eventDate.textContent = getDate(new Date());
            eventData.appendChild(eventCode);
            eventData.appendChild(eventDate);
            eventContainer.appendChild(eventData);
        }
        console.log = function () {
            var data = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
            genericRow(data);
            window.console.log.apply(null, arguments);
        }
        return console;
    }


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var engine = new CodeEngine();
        engine.init();
        engine.DOM.frame.contentWindow.console = new FrameConsole(engine.DOM.frame.contentWindow.document);
        var button = document.getElementById('run');
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            engine.execute();
        });

    });
})();
```

Comment: можно  пример кода с проблемой  ?  https://plnkr.co/edit/ благосклонен к примерам с iframe.

Comment: @zb' , да конечно секунду.

Comment: @zb' Вот: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ct2fvgdB0ANlYR2zjG3q?p=preview

Comment: @pepel_xD вы еще не научились пользоваться ruSO и не читали справку? почитайте где должен быть представлен код и как должен быть оформлен вопрос

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, для воспроизведения проблемы придется выложить весь работоспособный код иначе не понять сути проблемы... для минималистичности  были выложены скрины отладчика, причем данная проблема в хроме, в мозиле работает

Comment: а код в plnkr в ссылке в комментарии для кого? почему не в вопросе? я вот на что намекаю.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, а здешняя песочница блокирует выполнения скрипта с ошибкой: "Error: Permission denied to access property \"document\"",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 141,
  "colno": 17

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, как то проблематично запускать песочницу в песочнице.... там пришлось кое что изменить что бы запустился.... а здесь вообще доступ к свойству `document` ифрэйма закрыт, насколько я понял

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Чем разводить демогогию, подсказали бы лучше почему хром себя так ведет... где камень предкновения... а правила для того и нужны, что-бы их нарушать.....

Comment: @pepel_xD тогда может зарежете и изнасилуете кого-нибудь на досуге, раз правила для того, чтоб их нарушать?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, что за бред.... Вам флудить негде?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос корректный, я попросил plnkr, потому что местная песочница и fiddle не дают нормально работать со встроеным iframe.

Comment: @zb' ссылки могут быть добавлены в вопрос, это не запрещено, но все основное, так или иначе, в том числе код, если он есть, должно быть в вопросе, т.к. вопрос и ответы должны быть полезными для многих людей ибо этот ресурс — база знаний. Ссылки устаревают и сгорают и в итоге тот, кто еще придет уже может ничего не понять. В итоге получится, что это персональный бесплатный консультационный пункт конкретного человека.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну что вы такое говорите, в принципе, даже без кода понятно что произошло, код в вопросе работать не может, кроме того из моего ответа вполне ясна суть проблемы. А вот сниппетом этот код делать не нужно, т.к. запутает. Вообще надо бы упростить до минимума.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересный вопрос, в общем суть в том, что HTMLElement в текущем scope действительно, не тот же самый инстасом которого, является параграф, просто можете проверить, начиная в вашем console.log враппере

```
data[0].__ptoto__  === HTMLParagraphElement //false
```

чтобы "исправить", нужно прокинуть ещё и window в ваш "конструктор" консоли, примерно так получилось (смотрите по коду коменты // ТУТ)

```
(function () {
    /**
     * текстовые поля
     * 
     * @param {any} CSSClass 
     */
    function Field(CSSClass) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(CSSClass);
    }
    Field.prototype.write = function() {

    }

    /**
     * кнопки
     * 
     * @param {any} CSSClass 
     */
    function button(CSSClass) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(CSSClass);
    }


    /**
     * Класс обработчика и загрузчика кода в iframe  и ткстовые поля докуметта
     * Содержит ключи (объекты) со ссылками на DOM узлы основного документа и iframe
     * 
     */
    function CodeEngine() {
        this.DOM = {
            //cssText: document.querySelector('head style'),
            htmlText: document.querySelector('.html-container'),
            codeText: document.querySelector('body script'),
            frame: document.querySelector('.code_result iframe'),
            html: document.querySelector('.code_html textarea'),
            css: document.querySelector('.code_css textarea'),
            js: document.querySelector('.code_js textarea'),
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    CodeEngine.prototype.init = function () {
        /**
         * Adds the necessary DOM elements to the iframe
         * 
         * @returns  Item object in a iframe
         */
        function renderFrame() {
            var frame = this.DOM.frame.contentWindow.document;
            var docStyle = frame.createElement('style');
            var docHTML = frame.createElement('div');
            docHTML.setAttribute('id', 'contentHTML');
            var docScript = frame.createElement('script');

            return {style: docStyle, html: docHTML, script: docScript}

        }

        /**
         * Adds to the initial data in textarea
         * 
         */
        function renderFields() {
            this.DOM.js.value = this.DOM.codeText.innerHTML;
            this.DOM.html.value = this.DOM.htmlText.innerHTML;
            //this.DOM.css.value = this.DOM.cssText.textContent;
        }

        /**
         * Running code in the iframe
         * 
         */
        function execute() {
            var frame = this.DOM.frame.contentWindow.document;
            frame.body.innerHTML = '';

            this.frameDOM.style.textContent = this.DOM.css.value;
            this.frameDOM.html.innerHTML = this.DOM.html.value;
            //this.frameDOM.script.textContent = this.DOM.js.value;

            frame.head.appendChild(this.frameDOM.style);
            frame.body.appendChild(this.frameDOM.html);

            var eventContainer =  frame.createElement('div');
            eventContainer.className = 'console';
            frame.body.appendChild(eventContainer);

            frame.body.appendChild(this.frameDOM.script);

            var newScript = frame.createElement('script');
            newScript.textContent = this.DOM.js.value;
            frame.body.replaceChild(newScript, this.frameDOM.script);
            this.frameDOM.script = newScript;


        }

        renderFields.call(this);
        this.frameDOM = this.frameDOM ? this.frameDOM : renderFrame.call(this);
        this.execute = execute.bind(this);
        this.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Конструктор объекта консоли ифрэйма
     * 
     * @param {any} doc 
     * @returns объект консоли
     */
    function FrameConsole(doc, win) { //ТУТ
        var win = win;
        var console = Object.assign({}, window.console);
        var consoleStyle = doc.createElement('style');
        consoleStyle.textContent = ''; // вставить стили для консоли
        doc.head.appendChild(consoleStyle);

        /**
         * @param {any} e  new Date
         * @returns возвращает дату в виде строки "часы:минуты:секунды.миллисекунды"
         */
        function getDate(date) {
            date = new Date(date.valueOf() - 6e4 * date.getTimezoneOffset());
            var dateString = date.toISOString().replace("Z", "");
            return dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf("T") + 1);
        }

        /**
         * Преобразует входящие данные к строке
         * 
         * @param {any} data - входящие данные
         * @returns итоговый результат
         */
        // добавить вывод тегов
        function stringConvert(data) {
            var b = data[0].constructor;
            var c = data[0] instanceof HTMLElement;  //!!!!!!!! FALSE
            data.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
              //ТУТ
                if(item instanceof win.HTMLElement) { // true !!! :) //ТУТ
                    alert(true );
                } else {
                     alert(false);
                }

                switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(item)) {
                    case "[object Array]":
                    case "[object Object]":
                        arr[i] = JSON.stringify(item);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
        /**
         * генерирует строки в консоле
         * 
         * @param {any} data arguments метода console
         */
        function genericRow(data) {
            var eventContainer = doc.body.querySelector('.console');
            var eventDate = doc.createElement('span');
            var eventData = doc.createElement('p');
            var eventCode = doc.createElement('code');
            eventDate.className = 'console_date';
            eventData.className  = 'console_text';
            eventCode.className  = 'console_code';
            eventCode.textContent = stringConvert(data);
            eventDate.textContent = getDate(new Date());
            eventData.appendChild(eventCode);
            eventData.appendChild(eventDate);
            eventContainer.appendChild(eventData);
        }
        console.log = function () {
            var data = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);


            // ТУТ
            console.debug(data[0], data[0] instanceof HTMLElement, data[0] instanceof win.HTMLElement); // эта строчка поясняет ситуацию

            genericRow(data);
            window.console.log.apply(null, arguments);
        }
        return console;
    }


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var engine = new CodeEngine();
        engine.init();
        engine.DOM.frame.contentWindow.console = new FrameConsole(engine.DOM.frame.contentWindow.document, engine.DOM.frame.contentWindow); //ТУТ
        var button = document.getElementById('run');
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            engine.execute();
        });

    });
})();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/W3zqz8oLJxscbTIwgvNn?p=preview

вкратце это выглядит так:

## html

```
<iframe id="test"></iframe>
```

## js

```
var frameWindow = document.getElementById('test').contentWindow;
var frameDocument = frameWindow.document;
frameDocument.body.innerHTML='<p>test</p>';
var p = frameDocument.querySelector('p');
console.log(p instanceof HTMLElement, p instanceof frameWindow.HTMLElement);  // false, true
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/b21nNfj3R92lqYW9Zxkb?p=preview

в firefox это баг, т.к.

```
var frameWindow = document.getElementById('test').contentWindow;
var frameDocument = frameWindow.document;
frameDocument.body.innerHTML='<p>test</p>';
var p = frameDocument.querySelector('p');
HTMLElement.prototype.myTest = () => 'hello world';
try {
    console.log(p instanceof HTMLElement, p instanceof frameWindow.HTMLElement); // true, true
    console.log('LOL', document.getElementById('test') instanceof frameWindow.HTMLElement); // true
    console.log(document.getElementById('test').myTest()); // 'hello world'
    console.log(p.myTest()); // exception
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e); // myTest() is undefined...
}
```

ps: чтобы так не мучаться - передавайте эти данные сообщениями, библиотечку положите непосредственно во фрейм исполнения, тогда можно даже в sandboxed iframe делать (iframe src=dataURL)

Comment: Я понял, спасибо за разъяснения, не у того окна проверял. Сам бы и не догадался...